# ¿Como separar el valor de un campo según el valor de otro campo de la misma tabla?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, select

Deseo hacer un SELECT al idProducto, fecha, numFacura y la cantidad de la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no se como realizar el SELECT para que el idProducto no se repita y por cada producto me muestre la cantidad de tipo entrada y la cantidad de tipo salida en el mismo registro, ¿o es preferible  separar la tabla?
(en la tabla no existe una PrimaryKey solo ForeignKey que son el idProducto de la tabla productos y el numFactura de la tabla factura).

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganar tu [primera medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed) :-). Para que el producto no se repita en un ``select`` se usa ``distinct``, seria algo parecido a esto ``SELECT DISTINCT tuColumna1,tuColumna2 FROM tuTabla;``

Comment: No indicas como es la consulta actual, y eso es necesario para poderte ayudar bien. En todo caso según me parece debes usar la claúsula GROUP BY con el campo **idProducto** y en los campos a mostrar del SELECT realizar los cálculos para que haga la suma de las cantidades deseadas.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que pude entender de lo que necesitás, hice lo siguiente:

```
SELECT t.idProducto,
       t.tipo As Tipo_Entrada,
      t.cantidad As Cant_Entrada,
      'Salida' As Tipo_Salida,
      (Select t2.cantidad from tmp_prueba t2 where t.idProducto = t2.idProducto and t2.tipo = 'salida') As Cant_Salida
  FROM tmp_prueba t
 where t.tipo = 'entrada'
```

Si necesitas agragar más columnas asociadas al ID, haces lo mismo, creas un nuevo subquery con el dato a mostar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]